# Rails datastructure setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, taxonomy

Sorry for the somewhat ambiguous title, I'm not really sure how to phrase this.

My problem is that I have a complicated set up and am not sure the best way to approach a change request. I have the following models:

- Brands (`has_many :styles through :brand_styles`)
- Styles (`has_many :brands through :brand_styles` & `has_many :collections through :collection_styles`)
- Collections (`has_many :styles through :collection_styles`)
- Products (`belongs_to :collection`)

Up until this point a `product` would inherit a `brand` (or multiple brands) from `collections` > `styles`. However I now need to make a change so that a product can be unbranded, yet will still be in the same collection.

My initial thought was to make an "unbranded" model and with `brand_id` and `product_id` and check against that before displaying any kind of branding in the view. However I'm not sure how to set that up... I was thinking maybe a `has_many :through` relationship?

If anyone has any advice about a better way to do this or how to implement the solution I thought of it would be much appreciated!

Comment: belongs_to will accept only singular name association like `belongs_to :brand` according to rails convention

Comment: Sorry, I was trying not to make it too complicated. I'll update the question.

Comment: I think every Product belongs_to 1 Brand and if there is an unbranded product, it's brand_id column of the Products table would be "nil"

Comment: Unfortunately A product can belong to more than one brand. (It's not the most well organized dataset that I have to work with, and I can't change the original dataset)